# How to Use Guacamole API with QuickConnect Extension for RDP?

Tags: javascript, guacamole, guacamole-common.js

I'm trying to utilize the Guacamole API with the QuickConnect extension to establish remote desktop connections programmatically. However, I'm encountering some difficulties in the process. I've followed the documentation and attempted the following steps, but I'm unsure if they're correct:

Generated an API token using a POST request to /api/tokens.
Used the QuickConnect API to start a session with POST request to /api/quickconnect.
Could someone provide a clear example or step-by-step guide on how to use the Guacamole API along with the QuickConnect extension to initiate remote desktop connections? Specifically, I need assistance with the correct API endpoints, required parameters, and the correct sequence of actions.

I appreciate any insights or code examples that can help me achieve this goal.

I tried using this:

`curl -X POST "https://your-guacamole-server/guacamole/api/quickconnect?token=your-generated-token" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"protocol": "rdp", "hostname": "remote-machine-hostname", "port": rdp-port}'`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to launch a remote VM (EC2 instance) using Apache Guacamole API from a frontend application.

Answer (score 0):

The example below will create a connection using quickConnect extension and Guacamole API. The url and content-type need to be different than what you have in your example.

`curl -X POST "https://your-guacamole-server/guacamole/api/session/ext/quickconnect/create?token=your-generated-token" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "uri=rdp://username@remote-machine-hostname/?security=rdp&ignore-cert=true&disable-audio=true"`